# ICWT filtering signal with a cut-off frequency

Tags: filtering, cwt, ssqueezepy

In ssqueezepy, by finding a certain scale is it possible to do an icwt only for the scales above (or bellow) ? For exemple if I have a double sin (with *$f_1$* and *$f_2$*), by taking the frequency *$f_c$* such as *$f_1$* < *$f_c$* < *$f_2$*, going back to scales (*$a_1$*, *$a_2$* and *$a_c$*), can we integrate the scales from *$a_c$* (or to *$a_c$*) ? Would the resulting reconstructed signal would corresponds to the low frequency (or high frequency) part of my double sin ?

I tried by setting each of the elements that I didnt want to keep to zeros but the fact that it wasn't a linear scale anymore stopped it.
It seems that I also can't just cut scales array because the size between scales and coefficients would be different...

What's the way to do this ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know if my question was unclear or trivial (or both !) but I eventually end up doing what I wanted some time ago :

So I start by creating a double sinus with two frequencies f1 and f2

```
plt.style.use("ggplot")

fig = plt.figure()
ax = plt.axes()

sc = 80

N1 = 2000

f1 = 1/2
f2 = 1/10

n_T = sc * f1
t_max = n_T/f1 # change here max or min if you want highest or lowest frequency to be represented on n_T periods

t1 = np.linspace(0, t_max, N1)
y1 = np.sin(2*np.pi*f1*t1) + np.sin(2*np.pi*f2*t1)

plt.plot(t1,y1, color = "firebrick", label = "test N = 2000")

plt.legend(loc = "best", frameon=True, fancybox = True,
           shadow = True, facecolor = "white")

plt.axis([-0.05*t_max, 1.05*t_max, -2, 2])

plt.title("Sine Waves")
plt.xlabel("Time")
plt.ylabel("Amplitude")
```

[image]

Then I do a cwt of that signal and represent it in frequencies

```
wavelet = ('morlet', {'mu': 10})

Wx2, scales2, *_ = cwt(y2, wavelet, fs=N2, scales='log')
freq2 = scale_to_freq(scales2, wavelet, N2, fs=N2/sc)
power2 = (abs(Wx2)) ** 2

plt.axhline(y=242, color='white', linestyle='--', alpha = 0.9) #for N = 2000
plt.axhline(y=168, color='white', linestyle='--', alpha = 0.9) #for N = 2000
plt.axhline(y=200, color='red', linestyle='--', alpha = 0.9)
imshow(Wx2, abs=1, yticks=freq2, title="sin with N= {}".format(N2), show=1)
print(freq2[166])
print(freq2[240])
```

[image]

Here I identify my 2 frequencies f1 and f2 and select a frequency between the two, fc (in red, $f1 > fc >f2$). I want then to split my signal in two parts, everything below fc and everything above fc. To do so I perform an icwt for the two parts selected. Here it's simply a sin for each but it would be possible to extract a low frequency in a real signal for exemple if my parts are not too close or does not intertwine frequency whise.

```
highfreqparticwt = icwt(Wx2[:190], wavelet, scales1[:190])
lowfreqparticwt = icwt(Wx2[190:], wavelet, scales1[190:])
plt.plot(y1, color = "blue", label = "double sin")
plt.plot(2*lowfreqparticwt, color = "red", label = "low freq part")
plt.plot(highfreqparticwt, color = "green", label = "high freq part")
plt.legend(loc = "best", frameon=True, fancybox = True,
           shadow = True, facecolor = "white")
```

[image]

Where I obtain the two parts that I wanted. I still have to multply by a constant my low frequency part to match the envelope of the original signal.